# How to add Login/Register system to an existing database using ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My project is a web application that will be run in my own corporate. The authentication system doesn't need to store Email information. I want to create my own customized elements for authentication. I've created my own data model and then, created a database and all necessary tables and related columns for my project. You can see the created diagram in the image below:

[image: My model]

The User table stores all information about registered users and all other tables are related to this table. Can I use this table for authentication? Do I need to use `EntityFrameworkCore`? Identity to create a new `DbContext` and create a new database?

**Updated:**

My project has a database with multiple tables. One table is Users that have a key called userId. Other tables are Messages, Notifications, and Files that have a relationship with the User table through userId. I can create a User table (a customized Identity system) using EF Core Identity. The User table is created using a class inherited from IdentityDbContext class while other tables are created using a class inherited from DbContext class. My problem is that how can I create those other tables while keeping their relation.

Comment: yes, you can use this table for authentication, create a new web project with authentication and check the post Login action in Account Controller, and check what packages and what code you need to log in as a user then do it in your project.  That's it.

Comment: ASP.NET Core Identity requires quite a few things in order to work out of the box. You can use an existing model for this but you will have to expand it with a number of properties (or rather change your model to derive from the Identity models). Alternatively, you can also customize Identity quite a lot in order to use your model as is. That will require quite some work though since you will need to create your own UserManager/UserStore etc.

Comment: Please check the updated section in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally create my customized Identity and all other necessary tables. There is no need to use DbContext and IdentityDbContext at the same time. There is no need to have two migrations. Only IdentityDbContext can handle all.